# Json Decode dont show romanian caracters and show only ? simbol

Tags: php, mysql, json

i get from database a json data.

data contain a romanian simbols like a ĂÎȘȚÂ

and i use  code
`

```
$sql = "SELECT data FROM form_submission";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Check if there is any data
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // Set the character encoding to UTF-8 to display special characters
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

  // Display the data in a table
  echo "<table>";
  echo "<tr><th>Text 1</th><th>Text 2</th><th>Select List 1</th><th>Text 3</th><th>Text 4</th><th>Date 1</th><th>Email 1</th><th>Matrix 1 0</th><th>Matrix 1 1</th><th>Matrix 2 0</th><th>Matrix 2 1</th></tr>";

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Decode the JSON data into an associative array
    $data = json_decode($row["data"], true);

    // Display the data in the table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["text_1"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["text_2"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . implode(", ", $data["selectlist_1"]) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["text_3"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["text_4"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["date_1"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["email_1"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["matrix_1_0"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["matrix_1_1"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["matrix_2_0"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data["matrix_2_1"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }

  echo "</table>";
}
```

example a Json `{"text_1":"ăîțâș","text_2":"ăîșțâț","selectlist_1":["Cabinetul directorului general"],"text_3":"dfasd","text_4":"asdfasdf","date_1":"2023-02-24","email_1":"asdfads@afdsf.ff"}`

and all romain simbols display at ?

Comment: Assuming the correct charset is used in your database you can use [mysqli_set_charset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) to give the query the correct charset

Comment: Big Thanks... 

but my mysql charset is same with use in php ))

Comment: In your database is stored correct?

Comment: See "question marks" (not "black diamond") in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: @SimoneRossaini - That function establishes the charaset _in the client_.  It is independent of what charset is declared for the _table columns_.

Comment: "In your database is stored correct?" ;)